# Using while loop to write user input to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, file-writing

I have created a program that allows for a user to input their name in a text file I have. The problem is I now need to make it a while loop that allows for multiple names to be entered.

I was able to kind of get it with a for loop, but I am specifically looking for a while loop. Below is my code with no loop as of now.

```
filename = input ("visitor_log.txt: ");
with open("visitor_log.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(input("Please write your name:"));
```

The actual results would keep the names entered as a list that I could print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop has a condition, and the loop will continue to execute so long as the condition is true.

```
while some_condition:
    //Do some stuff
    //Change your condition if necessary
```

*While* the condition some_condition evaluates to True, the code inside the scope of your loop will continue to execute.  If your condition never becomes False, then your loop will execute forever.

What you need to do is decide condition you will use to continue looping through code, and then change that condition as necessary based on your input.  Here is my example which will read names until the word "END" is entered.

```
with open("visitor.txt", "a") as f:
    accept_more_visitors = True
    while accept_more_visitors:
        input_value = input("Please write your name, or 'END' if you are done.")
        if input_value == "END":
            break
        f.write(input_value)
```

One other key difference is that you are opening the file with the flag "w" which will overwrite the file.  You probably want the flag "a" which will append to the end of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped out a ton! I understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

```
# filename = input ("visitor_log.txt: ")

with open("./visitor_log.txt", "w") as f:
    text = ''

    while text != 'exit\n':
        text = raw_input("Please write your name:")
        print(text)
        text = str(text) + "\n"
        f.write(text)
```

`raw_input` is better `input` for text

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
names = []
while True:
    name = input ('Enter your name: ')
    names.append(name)
    if input ('Hit enter to add another name, or type done to continue') == 'done':
        break

towrite =''
with open("visitor_log.txt", "w") as f: 
        for name in names:
            towrite+= name + "\n"
         f.write(towrite)
```

What this does, is let the user enter as many names as they want, appends them to a list and writes the names to visitor_log.txt.

The names are stored in the names list, so you can iterate through that list and do what you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
filename = input ("visitor_log.txt: ")
with open("visitor_log.txt", "a") as f:
    i=0
    while (i<5):
        f.write(input("Please write your name:"))
        f.write('\n')
        i +=1
```